# Missing elements in periodic c3t3 mesh

Tags: cgal

I am using the periodic mesher of CGAL and running into the issue that it often produces meshes with a missing element or more. The issue happens with both coarser and finer meshes. Bellow are an image were one element can be seen missing (from each repetition) and a minimal code that should reproduce the problem.

[image]

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>

#include <CGAL/Periodic_3_mesh_3/config.h>
#include <CGAL/make_periodic_3_mesh_3.h>
#include <CGAL/optimize_periodic_3_mesh_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_3_mesh_3/IO/File_medit.h>

#include <CGAL/Periodic_3_mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Labeled_mesh_domain_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h>

#include <CGAL/number_type_config.h> // CGAL_PI

/* Standard library headers */
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT FT;
typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef K::Iso_cuboid_3 Iso_cuboid;

typedef FT (Function)(const Point&);
typedef CGAL::Labeled_mesh_domain_3<K> Periodic_mesh_domain;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_3_mesh_triangulation_3<Periodic_mesh_domain>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C3T3_Periodic;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Periodic_mesh_criteria;

using namespace CGAL::parameters;

// Implicit function
FT schwarz_p(const Point& p) {
double scaling = 2*CGAL_PI/1;
double t = -0.5;

return sin(scaling*p.x())*cos(scaling*p.y()) +
    sin(scaling*p.y())*cos(scaling*p.z()) +
    sin(scaling*p.z())*cos(scaling*p.x()) -
    t;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int domain_size = 1;

  Iso_cuboid canonical_cube(0, 0, 0, domain_size, domain_size, domain_size);
  Periodic_mesh_domain domain = Periodic_mesh_domain::create_implicit_mesh_domain(schwarz_p, canonical_cube);

  Periodic_mesh_criteria criteria(facet_angle = 30,
                                  facet_size = domain_size,
                                  facet_distance = 0.027 * domain_size,
                                  cell_radius_edge_ratio = 2.,
                                  cell_size = 0.027 * domain_size);

  C3T3_Periodic c3t3_Periodic = CGAL::make_periodic_3_mesh_3<C3T3_Periodic>(domain, criteria);

  std::ofstream medit_file("out.mesh");
  CGAL::IO::output_periodic_mesh_to_medit(medit_file, c3t3_Periodic, 8);

  std::cout << "EXIT SUCCESS" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, I'm currently working on improving the package, and I will look into this

Comment: Looking forward to the improvements! Since I know its possible to obtain surfaces without the 'holes' in them by playing with the face and cell sizes, but its basically a trial an error approach each time one changes the either the lattice type or its porosity which makes it cumbersome.

Comment: How did you create the .off in the image of the original post? Do you get this error consistently with default input and the code above? Is it a visual issue, or do you also have a broken triangulation (from a data structure point of view)?

Comment: I got the off file by extracting the surface facets from the output_periodic_mesh_to_medit output (which had the same issue). With the default input (the ones in the documentation example) I come across the issue less, but it still occurs at times.
One such case is the following implicit function:
double t = 0.8;
return std::pow((sin(scaling * p.x())*cos(scaling * p.y()) + sin(scaling * p.y())*cos(scaling * p.z()) + sin(scaling * p.z())*cos(scaling * p.x())), 2) - std::pow(t, 2);

Comment: Also, I do need to vary the default inputs to be able to check for mesh convergence for example.

Comment: Could you try with this (wip) branch: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/7062? I have not checked if it addresses your issue, but I have rewritten parts of the IO, so it might.

Comment: I am not able to check this one since I don't get the test code compiled with this branch, I also tried the examples provided with this branch and get the same error, i.e. ".../Periodic_3_triangulation_3.h:339:68: error: cannot declare parameter ‘tr’ to be of abstract type ‘CGAL::Periodic_3_triangulation_3<GT, TDS>’
  339 |   Periodic_3_triangulation_3& operator=(Periodic_3_triangulation_3 tr)"

Comment: Sorry, that error should be fixed now.

Comment: It still happens, although less often and not necessarily in the same cases as before. In addition, now I am also observing sort of the opposite happen at times, i.e. small clusters of elements protruding a bit from what should be the [surface](https://ibb.co/NZ5HHQ3). This is mostly with coarser meshes, so not sure if its just due to that or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have identified and fixed the issue(s) now:

- Clusters: an issue in projection of dummy verties (https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/7062/commits/cdc3bd22cf6218ecfdee1ea8d092f7afa86bfbab)
- Holes: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/7062/commits/06d272169feeeb6d4c0ad93d83f0624f1666becd

Could you please check the branch again (https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/7062)?

Comment: The issue with the clusters seems to be fixed in the new branch, the issue with holes not

Comment: I can't reproduce it this time, can you please give the specific input criteria and implicit function please? The mesher is deterministic.

Comment: One implicit function that should reproduce the issue is:
double scaling = 2 * CGAL_PI/1; double t = 0.3;
return std::pow((sin(scaling * p.x()) * cos(scaling * p.y()) + sin(scaling * p.y()) * cos(scaling * p.z()) + sin(scaling * p.z()) * cos(scaling * p.x())), 2) - std::pow(t, 2);

//With the following criteria:
Periodic_mesh_criteria criteria(facet_angle = 30, facet_size = 1, facet_distance = 0.03);